# Use Selection and Selection Args instead of URI matcher

Tags: android, android-sqlite, uri, android-contentprovider, android-database

I am confused the whole point of using URI matcher is to identify whether we want to work on particular row or the whole table. so in case we want to work on particular row with id "ID" we attach id to the path of URI and then URI matcher will identify what kind of URI pattern.

but on the other hand we can do the same without URI matcher, by simply putting the desired row ID in the selections Args of our query method.

so my question is why do we need A URI matcher?

```
      public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = petDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case PETS:
            cursor = database.query(PetContract.PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null,
                    null, null, null);
            break;
        case PET_ID:
            selection = PetContract.PetEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            cursor = database.query(PetContract.PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "query: leaving Pet Provider with a cursor");
    return cursor;
}
```